# In Reports, Show Currencies option will not default to Personal Currency

Tags: reporting, multi-currency, currency

**Overview:**

- So my organization has just activated the Multicurrency feature on one of our Sandbox environment for development and testing purposes.
- In one of our reports, there is a Currency field which we then summarize it's sum.
- The currency of each Record entry is in EUR but our Users wishes to see the sum of the values in USD or in EUR.
- In the Report's 'Show' > 'Currencies Using' it is defaulted to EUR.
- Now as is stated in [here](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_using_multiple_currencies.pdf), the default value is the User's Personal Currency. So if the User's Personal Currency is in USD, then the summary will be in USD otherwise it's EUR.
- I've seen this very effect on another report. I've seen the Summary headers change whenever I change my Personal Currency.

**Problem:**

- However, on another Report that has Currency fields being Summed up, I don't see the same thing happen. The 'Show' -> 'Currencies Using' is set to EUR and no matter how many times I change my Personal Currency, the Summary headers will remain as EUR.
- I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and I just cannot understand why this is happening.

Is this a Salesforce limitation? A bug? OR I'm likely missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Without the currency code, all amounts are assumed to be in the user's personal currency.
Is the currency specified on those records which you are trying to summarize in report?

Comment: Yes. The CurrencyIsoCode has been specified in the records before they were uploaded via Data Loader. The value of their CurrencyIsoCode is in EUR. For now, we don't mind about the Record Currency, we don't try to change them. We are more concern on the Summation of these records to the Personal Currency of the User. If Personal Currency of User is in USD, then the Summarized Header should display a Summary value of all these EUR records in USD.

Comment: I guess if the values are not supplied, then it would generate report in the User's currency..

Comment: Is the report being run as a specific user? That would cause it to have that users currency settings displayed.

Comment: Yes, the report is supposed to be run for a specific user. For example, 1 user wants to see the Summarized Headers in USD while another wants to see it in EUR. Now the CurrencyISOCode is set to EUR so no problem for the User wanting to see the Summarized Headers in EUR. The problem occurs for the User wanting to see it in USD. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the reason for this problem and it's absolutely very strange in my honest opinion.

**Short Answer:**
The Problem was caused by the Currency being set in the Reports (in Show Currencies using) SUPERSEDING the Personal Currency of the User.

**Long Answer:**
The User wishes to see the Summarized Headers of the Reports in his own Personal Currency.

For example:

Records 1, 2, 3 are all in USD (CurrencyIsoCode = USD). However, User wishes to see the total of these records as converted to EUR (this is his Personal Currency) in the Summarized Header of the Report.

We expected this to be the case since we've actually seen another Report whose Summarized Header changes depending on the User's current Personal Currency.

But apparently this is not the case. Whatever is being set in the Report's currency setting (Show --> Currencies Using --> EUR) will SUPERSEDE the Personal Currency of the User.

The reason why we could easily change the currency of the Summarized Header in the other Report was that, we never touched it after we activated Multicurrency.

If you will retrieve the xml for this Report in Eclipse, you will see that it does not have a tag called:

```
<Currency>EUR</Currency>
```

While the Report that has that tag lost it's dynamism in having the currencies in its Summarized Headers as that of the User's Personal Currency.

So our Solution then is to retrieve our Reports to Eclipse and ensure to erase the tag EUR so Personal Currency can be used.

Sort of Off Topic:
It is really strange for Salesforce not to add the option in the Reports that would allow us to choose to use the Personal Currency of the User in order to achieve a sort of dynamism in the Reports rather than making it all Static.

Comment: Simply brilliant!