# Amount and Converted Amount currency shows different currencies for different reports

Tags: multi-currency, currency, convertcurrency

I am logged in with a user that has the currency set to SEK. When I create dashboards referencing reports on opportunities, where the graphs should show the Sum of Amount, some of the graphs show SEK but some show JPY. It doesn't seem to matter what the original currency was.

Original report referencing opportunities with more than 20 different currencies, uses SEK

[image]

Original report referencing opportunities with several currencies. **None of them are in JPY, yet the summary is in JPY.**

[image]

I tried to look in the report settings but I couldn't find anything that allows me to change the currency that it should convert to ([like this post suggested](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/in-reports-show-currencies-option-will-not-default-to-personal-currency)). Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384322&type=1

Comment: Cheezus now I feel like an idiot haha :) I was looking for that setting but couldn't find it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the reporting currency in [both Classic and LEX](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384322&type=1)

```
Steps to update the displayed currency within Salesforce Classic:
1. Open a report for which you want to change the currency from default currency
2. Click Customize
3. Click Show
4. Click Currencies Using
5. Select Currency from dropdown in which you want to display on report from default currencies
6. Click Run Report

 

Steps to update the displayed currency within Lightning Experience:
1. Open a report for which you want to change the currency from default currency
2. Click Edit
3. Click Currency (right side at the bottom)
4. Select Currency from dropdown in which you want to display on report from default currencies
5. Click Run


Note: The currency you select in the report will also apply to any dashboard component based on the report.
```